# Upserting column add to current value with simple.data

Tags: c#, .net, upsert, simple.data

Trying to upsert with simple.data and i would like to add to current value if matched, and otherwise just use provided value.

This fails if Id=13 does not exist.

```
var table = db.TheTable2;
table.UpsertById(Id: 13, Value: table.Value + 10); // Want a row ID=13, Value=10 if not exist, otherwise Value=Value+10.
```

This works because Id=13 exists

```
var table = db.TheTable2;
table.UpsertById(Id: 13, Value: 10);
table.UpsertById(Id: 13, Value: table.Value + 10);
```

How to do?

Comment: What is your implementation of `UpsertById`

Comment: Its for simple.data added to title

Comment: When the record doesn't exist what is the value of table.Value? If it is null then this might be the problem and you could use table.UpsertById(Id: 13, Value: (table.Value ?? 0) + 10);

Comment: @AndyNichols: Then i get: Failed to convert parameter value from a MathReference to a Int32. Same as when not ?? 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not supported at present. You could open an issue at https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data/issues to request the feature.